# Display Hebrew Characters in android

Tags: java, c#, android, encoding, hebrew

I'm trying to send from c# to java(android), via tcp a string that contains hebrew characters.

However, the data that comes to java are question marks.

Here the relevant code:

C# (m_client is tcpclient class):

```
NetworkStream stream = client.m_client.GetStream();
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Java(Android):

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_client.getInputStream(),"Windows-1255"));
char[] buffer = new char[1024]; 
input.read(buffer);
return new String(buffer);
```

I've tried all kinds of encoding in the java part (windows-1255,UTF-8,ASCII,iso-8859-8-i,iso-8859-8), but nothing seems to work

my OS is windows 7
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: try on C# side use utf8 encoding. I think ASCII doesn't support hebrew

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was the problem also, my language in the android needed to be in hebrew and also make the encoding both java and c# to UTF-8

Comment: Glad to hear it worked and thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the device go to settings/language&input and make sure the language is Hebrew or how do you say Hebrew in Hebrew. This should set the device [locale](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) I don't show it listed but then again I don't know Hebrew.  Part of the headers in a http request specifically Accept-Language: [lain/hebrew](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/hebrew.html) and  [this](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646.txt) Hebrew is part of utf-8 but you do have the right to left thing. This [trick](http://www.herongyang.com/PHP-Chinese/Web-Form-Input-UTF-8-Alt-Keycodes-Test.html) could be useful if you don't have a Hebrew keyboard for testing. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("Windows-1255")));
```